# SAS Macro variable with single quote

Tags: sas

Is it possible in SAS to have following macro variable:

```
%let macvar=User's request;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this answer: [Unmatched quotation mark issue in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5955770/), it looks like you need something like the following.

```
%let macvar=%str(User%'s request);
```

This should escape the single quote effectively. It looks like this is a complex issue in SAS since there are numerous extended results to "SAS macro escape character" and similar searches on Google.